# Let $f : R → R$ be a continuous function. Let $A$ be a bounded set in $R$ and $B $ be a closed and bounded set in $R.$ Then

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : R → R$ be a continuous function. Let $A$ be a bounded set in $R$ and   $B $  be a closed and
bounded set in $R.$ Then

which of the following option is corrects ?

a.$ f(A) $ is bounded and $f(B) $ is closed and bounded.

b. If $ x_n → x $ in $A,$ then $f(x_n) → f(x) $ in  $f(A)$.

c. $f(A)$ is not bounded and $f(B)$ is closed.

d. $f(A)$ is not bounded and $f(B)$ is bounded.

I thinks  option a) and b)  is  coorect  because closed map  to closed map  as continious image  of  closed  set is closed

Any hints /solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that if $A$ is bounded, then $f(A)$ isn't necessarily bounded. Take $A = (0,1)$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. We see that $f$ is continuous on $A$, but $f(A)$ is not bounded. This rules out a.

Comment: But this doesn't mean $f(A)$ _can't_ be bounded! If you let $f$ be the identity, then what do you see? Lastly for b, think back to the definition of continuity.